# Flash taskbar icon without bringing application to foreground

Tags: windows, mfc, taskbar

I've looked at the various solutions for flashing an application icon in the taskbar but they all bring the window to the foreground when minimized. What I've done so far:

```
void CNotifyDlg::FlashIcon()
{
    FLASHWINFO info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(FLASHWINFO);
    info.dwFlags = FLASHW_TRAY | FLASHW_TIMERNOFG;
    info.uCount = 5;
    info.dwTimeout = 0;
    info.hwnd = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd();

    ::FlashWindowEx(&info);
}
```

In the function where the dialog is shown, I have the following:

```
LRESULT CBaseViewGridCombos::OnShowNotify(WPARAM id, LPARAM cnt)
{
    int newCount = getNotifyDlg(id)->addCount(cnt);
    getNotifyDlg(id)->setText(getNotifyText(newCount));
    getNotifyDlg(id)->setDetails(getNotifyDetails());
    getNotifyDlg(id)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNA);
    getNotifyDlg(id)->FlashIcon();

    //Other tries
    //getNotifyDlg(id)->SetForegroundWindow();
    //getNotifyDlg(id)->SetFocus();
    //::SetForegroundWindow(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd());
    //AfxGetMainWnd()->SetForegroundWindow();

    return 1;
}
```

I'm testing the application on Windows 10 so that might also be a reason although, from the documentation, it should not be.

So what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
info.dwFlags = FLASHW_TRAY | FLASHW_TIMERNOFG;
```

`FLASHW_TIMERNOFG` means "Flash continuously until the window comes to the foreground," so you may only want the `FLASHW_TRAY` flag.

*** Edit: found something crazy ***

This is weird, and the opposite of anything I would expect, but it came up in testing and seemed worth mentioning:

```
::SetForegroundWindow(info.hwnd);
```

removes the highlight without restoring the window. At least, for me.

I let it `Sleep()` for a few seconds while blinking before calling `SetForegroundWindow`

Comment: With only `FLASHW_TRAY` the behaviour is the same: whenever the notification triggers the application is brought to the foreground.